# How override cursor when dragging out the app?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, cursor

Is it possible to override standart "Stop" (crossed circle) cursor when I drag and drop outside the main window? I have very simple code and that is enough for me. I drag PushButton outside the main window and on release mouse button I get window where mouse was released. Like a standart Windows Spy. So how can I override cursor outside the main window?

header

```
class DDButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DDButton(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
```

cpp

```
void DDButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
     if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {

         QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
         QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;

         drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
         drag->setPixmap(cursor.pixmap());
         drag->setHotSpot(QPoint(0,0));

         //This block not working
         QCursor cursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
         drag->setDragCursor(cursor.pixmap(), Qt::IgnoreAction);

         Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec();

         //Do something
         qDebug()<<"Press";
     }
}
```

Comment: `drag->setDragCursor(cursor.pixmap(), Qt::IgnoreAction);` will not work because: "The action can only be CopyAction, MoveAction or LinkAction. All other values of DropAction are ignored."  But I too would like to know how override the "stop" cursor.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I came across this  in the Qt 5.11 documentation:
`void QDrag::setDragCursor(const QPixmap &cursor, Qt::DropAction action)`

*Note: setting the drag cursor for IgnoreAction may not work on all platforms. X11 and macOS has been tested to work. Windows does not support it.*